How to include highcharts in Nuxt 3.7.0?
How can I include this combination graph https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/combo-dual-axes chart in my nuxt vue application ?
I followed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue docs, but could not get how to integrate this package with my nuxt vue application.
In the docs it is mentioned that for vue 3 I should use this
// for Vue 3
app.use(HighchartsVue)
But no where in my nuxt application I have something like app.use().
I am getting this :  Failed to resolve component: highcharts
This is my index.vue file
<template>
<highcharts :constructorType="'stockChart'" 
:options="testOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
  import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
  import Highcharts from 'highcharts-vue'

  export default {
  name: 'Home',

  data() {
    return {
        testOptions: {
            series: [{
                data: [1, 2, 3] // sample data
            }]
        },
      }
    },
  }

</script>

<style></style>

Can someone please tell me how can I properly import this highcharts-vue packages and get the desired graph I need ?

Please reproduce the issue in an online editor I could work on. Here's a basic template of Highcharts Vue demo, it may be helpful in terms of importing the library: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xenodochial-wood-6jctd6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

I managed to add a simple plot of hightcharts with Nuxt link. Can you please help me with this : I need to have the graph dynamically, I mean x-axis data and y-axis data will keep changing and I need to replot the graph whenever that happens.

Please take a look at the answer my colleague posted below.

If you'd like to use the officially supported highcharts-vue package in your Nuxt 3 project, here are some steps to make it work (Highcharts is a client-side library so it requires an additional setup so that Nuxt knows to handle it on the client-side only):

Create a highcharts.client.js file in the /plugins directory for Nuxt:

import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock';

export default defineNuxtPlugin({
   name: 'highcharts-vue',
   parallel: true,
   setup (nuxtApp) {
       if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
           stockInit(Highcharts);
       }
       nuxtApp.vueApp.use(HighchartsVue);
   }
});

In this file you can set up Highcharts with the modules that you'd like to use.

Register the plugin in your nuxt.config.ts file:

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ... the rest of your config
    plugins: [
        // Ensure this runs on client side only
        { src: '~/plugins/highcharts.client.js', mode: 'client' }
    ]
});


Use the highcharts component in your .vue files:

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const options = ref({
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>

Please let me know if that works for you.

Thank you for the answer, I created a sandbox link for this project. Any idea on how to make the categories in xAxis and data in series for chartOptions dynamic ?

The "options" props in highcharts-vue is dynamic (reactive) - meaning that when the props changes, these changes will apply on the chart. Currently, I can't see you making any changes to the chartOptions that you pass to the highcharts-vue component. If you modify them somewhere in your code, these changes will apply visually on the chart.

Thank you this worked for me. If possible could you please share on how you came up with highcharts.client.js

It's based on the following:
Nuxt Vue plugins documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins
HighchartsVue setup: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue?tab=readme-ov-file#registering-globally-as-a-plugin
